# Fabric Twitter Login issue when account is not setup?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, twitter, twitter-fabric

I am using Twitter's fabric too login via twitter & to get user's detail. I am using below code for that.

```
[[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^
     (TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
         if (session) {
             NSLog(@"signed in as %@", [session userID]);
         } else {
             NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
         }
     }];
```

It is working fine when I have configured twitter account in settings of iPhone i.e. added user name & password in twitter app of iPhone.
But if that is blank & no twitter account is configured I can not login & will get the error Request failed: unauthorized (401)

Is there any way in which I can ask user to enter his/her username & password ?

Thanks in advance.

-Aakil

Comment: In my case: Turn off network, then calling logInWithCompletion: method to login. It will present a blank UI without dismiss button.
When debug view hierarchy, I found keyWindow's rootViewController is replacing an empty view. so, I must to reset my rootViewController. [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController = [MyViewController new];

Answer (score 7):

Okay so I figured this out for anyone that happens to find this.
Go to you developer.twitter app (their website).

Add a callback URL in the apps settings. (doesn't matter what it is)

The button will work now.

Answer (score -1):

You can check like this :

```
if (![TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]) {
    NSLog(@"No Twitter Accounts");
}
```

if you want without going settings you need to use fabric way login. In documentation they use button, I don't know your application's lifecycle but at this point you can show this button somewhere and ask them to login maybe. here is some code from documentation :

```
TWTRLogInButton* logInButton =  [TWTRLogInButton
                                     buttonWithLogInCompletion:
                                     ^(TWTRSession* session, NSError* error) {
    if (session) {
         NSLog(@"signed in as %@", [session userName]);
    } else {
         NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
logInButton.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:logInButton];
```

hope it helps.

Comment: yes I know that but what if  I want user to login without configuring account in settings ?

Comment: @gyer The button doesn't work if there's no twitter account in your settings... it just says unauthorized.